# Check if an object in params object[] is Nullable<T>

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static bool IsNullable<T>(T t)
    {
        return false;
    }
    static bool IsNullable<T>(T? t) where T : struct
    {
        return true;
    }
    static void Test(params object[] objs)
    {
        for (int iter = 0, limit = objs.Length; iter < limit; ++iter)
        {
            var obj = objs[iter];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", iter, IsNullable(obj) ? "yes" : "no");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(new int?(100));
    }
}
```

I'm passing some numbers as `nullables` to a function so they are replaced with `null` if `0` for adding to DB. I figured it's an easy and meaningful way of doing this without creating a new data type. But... it doesn't work.

So I'm trying to test the `objs` for a `Nullable` type. **Can this be done?** The `Nullable<T>` is converted to `T` when if gets into the `params object[]`.

I'll use a custom data type for sure but why is this not working as I thought it would?

**PS**: *I'm VERY new to `C#`.*

Comment: A better question is why are you using object array instead of something more specific?

Comment: Tried [Nullable.GetunderlyingType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @user3411327 Yes. Not working either.

Comment: quoting directly from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx:

" where T: struct   
 The type argument must be a value type. **Any value
 type except Nullable can be specified.** See Using Nullable Types (C#
 Programming Guide) for more information."

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Wait so you basically don't have a type but want to know if it is nullable. You have something with static type object which is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first is that with the exception of `dynamic` (which you aren't using), all other method calls are resolved at compile time. Your call to `IsNullable(obj)` will *always* call `IsNullable<object>` version, because `obj`'s static type is just `object`.

The second is that nullable types have special rules for boxing (converting to `object`): `null` becomes a true null reference, and non-null values become the underlying type. There is no way to distinguish `o1` and `o2` in

```
object o1 = 100;
object o2 = new int?(100);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, so I can only explain what's wrong, not suggest any alternative.

Comment: **Thanks.** I know how to work around it. I just tried to be lazy and... failed. Figured out what you said here from testing but wanted to get a better explanation for it.

Comment: Another perspective is that since the boxed value is stored in an `object` reference, it is ALWAYS nullable.